# Get list of workers with required skills

Tags: sql

I have a table with the skills required to work.
For example, the level of skill 1 needs to be 2 or higher, and the level of skill 2 needs to be 3 or higher. (Levels go from 1 to 4).

[image]

Then I have another table with the skills that each worker has.

[image]

How can I check which workers have all the skills required? In this case, only worker 2 has the skills required because the current level of skill 1 is higher or equal to the minimumlevel, and the same for skill 2.

Is this possible to do using just sql queries?

Comment: `join on a.skill = b.skill and a.minimumlevel <= b.currentlevel`

Comment: Why did you tag this with python?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

I think you need SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT W.Worker
FROM Workers W
INNER JOIN Skills S USING (Skill)
GROUP BY W.Worker
HAVING every(W.CurrentLevel >= S.MinimumLevel) -- for MySQL only
```

Comment: you have a typo HAVING not HAWING and a LEFT JOIN makes no sense, he wants only workers that have the level needed

Comment: Agreed. Im used to work with dictionaties via LEFT JOIN, sorry)

Comment: HAVING will check the result set after mysql joins both tables, adding the condition to the join will reduce the number of rows significantly that will be returned by the join